# Angular routing in Spring Boot web application

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, angularjs-routing

I'm developing some project using **angular and spring boot** and I have some confussing situation:

I have Spring Controller to share view file names with my application

```
@Controller
public class OfferViewController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addOffer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addView() {
        return "html/offer/addOffer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showOffer/{offerId}")
    public String showOffer(@PathVariable("offerId") String offerId){
        return "html/offer/showOffer";
    }
}
```

And I have some other controller to handle REST calls:

```
@RestController
public class OfferRestController {

    private OfferRepository offerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public OfferRestController(OfferRepository offerRepository) {
        this.offerRepository = offerRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showOfferJson/{offerId}", method = GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Offer showOffertest(@PathVariable("offerId") String offerId) {
        Offer offer = offerRepository.findOne(offerId);
        return offer;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveOffer", method = POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Offer> saveOffer(@RequestBody Offer offer) {
        Offer offerSaved = offerRepository.save(offer);
        return new ResponseEntity<Offer>(offerSaved, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I use angular for develope my UI.

I find myself confused when I start to read about routing possibilities in angular (single page application stuff) so as I assume i dont need **OfferViewController** any more.

**My question are:**

1. Should I have an single index.html page to manage all ng-routes?
   For example ngRoute first to addOffer.html second to contact.html etc.?
2. Do I still need Controller to provide my starting page with all ngRout'ings?
3. Mby I'm wrong so please give me an advice how to do ngRouting right.

Thank You for any help!

Comment: You don't need it to handle routes like it's doing now. But it is better if this controller would allow HTML5 routing by responding with landing page for every request (except static files like CSS, JS, images).

Comment: I hope I answered all of your questions. If you have more questions please comment under the answer.

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets start with: **What is a single page application?**

A single page application is a page consisting on one single HTML-page. So there is only one HTML-File requested from your backend and the rest of the routing should be managed of the frontend.
For more detailed exaplanation of a single page application I am sure there is a lot of information in the web about that.

**How does routing with AngularJS work?**

Angular pathes to go to different routes are after the '#'. So they are in the fragment part of the url and this part is not transfered to the server. So there is no need to have a @Controller in the backend to serve different html.

To show different content depending on the current route you can specify controller and partial.html files which should be shown at the required route.

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/phones', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
    controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
  }).
  when('/phones/:phoneId', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
    controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/phones'
  });
}]);
```

this code example is right out of the [AngularJS Tutorial - Routing Part](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07). It shows how to specify a route and which content should be shown at this route.

This code snippet tells angular to include the partial HTML-File into every Element which uses the `ng-view` directive.

so your index.html could look like this (again copied out of the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07))

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

if you visit `yourdomain.com/#/phones` now it loads your index.html and angular includes the html contained in the file "/partials/phone-list.html" into the div which uses the `ng-view`-directive

**What is REST?**

I think no one knows the EXACT answer to this question but what you do is definitly NOT REST. It's simply HTTP calls. Your endpoint looks like RPC.
A first step could be to use an endpoint /offers/{id} which accepts a GET-Request and an endpoint /offers which accepts a POST-Request. If you want to provide a way to expose all of your offers at once add an endpoint /offers which accepts a GET-Request.

Comment: Thank You for response it highlight me how it should work. If You have a while please look at another question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370442/angular-simple-routing-is-not-working/34372529#34372529

Comment: I will have a look at it. If your project is available on github it would be nice to get the link for it so i can make it work and upload it as one of my examples on my github account (reduced to the essential content to demonstrate an angularJS application with a spring boot backend)

Comment: very late.. but nice explanation