# Angular simple routing is not working

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm tring build single page app, but i have problem with angular routing it doesnt work.

I'm using spring boot, thymeleaf and angular 1.4.8.

I'm basing on this example https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Here is my main controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head ng-app="ngViewExample">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
        <a href="#/test">test</a>

    <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/angular.js}" />
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/angular-route.js}" />
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/angular-resource.js}" />
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/underscore.js}" />
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/restangular.js}" />
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/src/index.js}" />
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
 var home = angular.module('ngViewExample', ['ngRoute']);

home.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/test', {
                templateUrl: 'test.html',
                controller: 'TestCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'test'
            })
    }])

    .controller('MainCtrl',
        function() {

        })
    .controller('TestCtrl', 
        function() {

    });
```

And content I wish to pass to ng-view

test.html

```
<div>
    Hello
</div>
```

Everything is loading fine but routing just not working here.

Comment: I'm tring access http://localhost:8080/#/test

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you linked me this question yesterday:

here my answer so far

Let's start with **How to provide static content via Spring Boot**

As shown in [this spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) all resources placed in the directories

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

inside your classpath are added as static resources. So for example just put your index.html into the /public/ directory inside your classpath and you won't need your `HomeController`anymore

**Now to the angular part**

First of all put the ng-app directive at the `<html>`or the `<body>` tag.
I can't see any problems with your angular code so far. Can you verify, that the partial HTML is available at the /test endpoint? If not please follow the steps i told you above. Just put the test.html inside the `/public/`directory inside your classpath.

Are there any errors in the console if you open the browser devtools and reload the page?

If you could provide your project on Github i will have a look at it.

Comment: Thank You for answer my problem were, ng-app was in unpropper place and templateUrl was wrong should be templateUrl: 'test' i had templateUrl: 'test.html'. Thank You verry much for answer and Merry Christmas :)

Comment: Nice to hear that it works, but i still would not suggest to provide static content via custom controllers. Make use of spring boot :) if you do so your previous url was right. if you have a reason to do use custom controllers i don't now i would like to hear it. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: I think custom controller could be usefull in security reasons, but You are right i should use spring boot as it should be used :) If I put my file in /public/test.html angular routing templateUrl: 'test.html' is ok, If i use /templates directory and register View angular routing templateUrl: 'test' is ok

Comment: If you don't want do offer the templates without authentication put it in directory /public/templates/ and make a security rule for /templates/**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Please ng-app directive placement `<body>` or `<html>` tag

```
<body ng-app="ngViewExample">
```

Template url

```
templateUrl: 'test'
```

MvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/test").setViewName("test");  
  }
}
```

SpringBootApp

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.spring"})
public class SpringAngularApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(SpringAngularApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where do you put test.html. It should be in /resources/static folder. If in /resources/templates it will be process by thymeleaf and need to be added in `ViewControllerRegistry`

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/test").setViewName("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have add this `@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter forwardToIndex() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addViewController("/test").setViewName("test");
            }
        };
    }` To my config file when I'm accesing it by `localhost:8080/test` `Hello` appears but still routing from index.html is not working

Comment: do you see javascript syntact error. I think `.when` need a ;

Comment: `templateUrl: 'test.html' ` should be `templateUrl: 'test'`

Comment: I have seted templateUrl: 'test.html' to templateUrl: 'test' and it still didn't working, do You have any more idea what could be wrong there?

Comment: html files should be in /templates directory, /static directory is for js, css

Comment: thats right for a spring mvc application. You have an angular app which is consuming a http backend.