# Spring Boot rest controller returning jsp

Tags: java, rest, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a springboot application with a rest controller up top. The controller receives an input from the user via the url, performs some operation, and prints out the results on the screen. I would like to return a jsp page instead that formats that data nice and neat for the user to read.

Here was my rest controller previously when I just spit out the value on the screen:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/weather", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getWeather(@RequestParam(value="zip") String zip) {
    StringBuilder sBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    Weather weather = weatherOperation.getWeather(zip);
    sBuffer.append(weather.getFarenheit());
    sBuffer.append("<br>");
    sBuffer.append(weather.getChanceOfPercipitation());
    sBuffer.append("<br><br><br>");

    return sBuffer.toString();
}
```

I tested this over a hundred times by access the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/weather?zip=10001
```

And it worked like a charm in all my test cases.

Here's my rest controller now trying to return a jsp page:

```
@RestController
public class AlertController {
    private final WeatherOperation weatherOperation;

    public AlertController(WeatherOperation weatherOperation) {
        this.weatherOperation = weatherOperation;
    }

    // RESTful method
    @RequestMapping(value="/weather", produces={"application/json"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody Weather listWithMarshalling(String zip) {
        return weatherOperation.getWeather(zip);
    }

    // View-based method
    @RequestMapping("/weather")
    public String list(@RequestParam(value="zip") String zip, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(listWithMarshalling(zip));
        return "views/testpage";
    }
}
```

Here's my javaconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    // Will map to the JSP page: "WEB-INF/jsp/views/testpage.jsp"
    @Bean(name="jspViewResolver")
    public ViewResolver getJspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/views");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

And finally my file structure:

```
Project
 +-- webapp
 |  |  
 |  +-- WEB-INF
 |  |
 |  |   +-- jsp
 |  |   |
 |  |   |   +-- views
 |  |   |   |
 |  |   |   |   +-- testpage.jsp
```

But every time I try to access the url `http://localhost:8080/weather?zip=10001` I just get the string "views/testpage" instead of the actual page. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @kryger i did not find my answer there

Comment: There's just one answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35460051/1240557

Comment: try return ModelAndView instead String. guess RestController has another handler for methods returning String than Controller. also you should fix prefix or view name cuz both have 'views' in name.

Comment: @kryger not sure that you are right about just one answer. will try it some later