# Spring boot with AngularJs using @RestController and @GetMapping

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-boot

I have found a lot of examples that ask similar questions. However, most of the advice says to just use @Controller instead of @RestController when you want to use:

```
//@Controller
@RestController // @Controller and @ResponseBody into one
public class SreAppController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Since this just returns the String index and does not fetch the HTML file index.html. I know that @ResponseBody, which is in the @RestController tag, renders the output as is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459040/spring-boot-with-angularjs) question. So, I found [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) tutorial which gives this code:

```
@RestController
public class SreAppController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting index(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name){
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Which I would like to use with AngularJS and format using HTML. [This](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/) tutorial shows how to consume a RESTful web service, but shows how to consume from http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting. I tried putting localhost:8080/greeting in it's place, but that still just gives a 404 error for localhost:8080 and just returns json for localhost:8080/greeting.

How do I use @RestController with AngularJS and HTML in one application? The intention is to go to localhost:8080 and get the same output as this tutorial:

[image]

I know the json from localhost:8080/greeting is coming straight from the Rest controller. I am not sure why the angularJS controller is not found when using localhost:8080.

The tutorial states the need for a minimal amount of web application code so Spring Boot knows to start Tomcat. The suggest app.groovy (shown below) but my rest controller starts the embedded Tomcat server, so I don't think this is the issue.

**app.groovy**

```
@Controller class JsApp { }
```

Javascript and html for reference:

**app.js**

```
"use strict";
angular.module('demo', []).controller('app', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/greeting').
            then(function (response) {
            $scope.greeting = response.data;
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demo">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="app">
        <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Hierarchy of project**

[image]

Comment: `$http.get('localhost:8080/greeting')` should be `$http.get('http://localhost:8080/greeting')`, or simply `$http.get('/greeting')`. Open your browser dev tools, and look at the requests you send in the network tab. Also, why use angularjs 1.4.3, and not the latest version?

Comment: I changed that part of the question to be more descriptive. I changed it to $http.get('/greeting'). I just used it from the tutorial on spring's documents. I updated that know! Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? Is it that you can't even see your HTML page? Where is it located in your project?

Comment: I cannot get the html file or angularjs file to load which gives the 404 error for localhost:8080. When I add /greeting to it, it goes to the rest controller and displays json. I want to go to localhost:8080 and have angular fetch the data from /greeting and the rest controller, but I am not sure how. Probably something wrong with how I set up Spring boot. The tutorial states that you have to let Spring boot's embedded Tomcat server serve static content and they use a empty controller. I want to use my rest controller. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Where are the index.html and app.js files located in your project? How do you build and run it?

Comment: both in the resources folder (I added a screen shot to question). I build and run using "mvn spring-boot:run" and I have also ran from the Run button in Intellij IDEA

Comment: That's the problem.It should be under src/main/resources/public or src/main/resources/static: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: Darn, that was a dumb mistake on my part! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you intend to do is accessing your AngularJS application which is inside a Spring Boot application but the index.html doesn't show, innit?

Then you need to know a couple of things:

**1) Your AngularJS application must be served as static content.**

You can find some examples at this tutorial: [Serving Static Web Content with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot).

Basically, your AngularJS app must be placed inside the Spring Boot app source code in a special folder used for static content - there are several options but tipically it will be named /public or /static.

**2) Spring Boot manages all your URLs.**

This means the Spring Boot app intercepts all request to your application and then tries to match the URLs against all the existing @Controller.

So if you `GET http://<your ip:port>/` and you have a @Controller mapping the root `/` with `GET`, then that @Controller will respond to the request, as it happens in the first example of your `SreAppController` class.

But if you don't then Spring Boot will try to find static content on every one of the special folders for that and - it found - serve it.

Beware you can mix ULRs in Controllers and static web navigations...!

Hope I helped at least a little bit. :-)